# How to attach screenshot in detailed cucumber report (mkolisnyk)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I was able to see the screenshot when i was using info.cukes but after upgrading to io.cucumber 3.0.1 screenshot disappear.

I can see its embedded in json report file but not showing in html report generated by mkolisnyk library.

it stop generating screenshot folder.

```
    public void generateCucumberReport(String reportName) {

    CucumberDetailedResults results = new CucumberDetailedResults();
    ReportDirectory.cleanReportFolder();
    results.setOutputDirectory(Constants.Report.Folder.RESULT);
    results.setOutputName(reportName);
    File pathToFiles = new File(Constants.Report.Folder.JSON);
    File[] files = pathToFiles.listFiles();
    List<String> jsonReportFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (files.length == 0) {
        logger.error("JSON report directory is empty");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].getName().substring(files[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1).equals("json")) {
                jsonReportFileList.add(files[i].getPath());
            }
        }
    }
    results.setSourceFiles(jsonReportFileList.toArray(new String[jsonReportFileList.size()]));
    results.setScreenShotLocation("screenshots/image");
    try {
        results.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred while generating Cucumber report.");
    }

}
```

this `results.setScreenShotLocation("screenshots/image");` folder was generated automatically but now its not.

Comment: The report plugin only supports upto version 1.2.5.